# Testing graph planarity in R

Tags: r, igraph, network-analysis, planar-graph

Is there a way of testing whether a network graph is planar in R? I've looked in igraph but to no avail.

I know I can with MATLAB using BGL toolbox but I want to know if anyone has tried it in R.

Comment: [https://answers.launchpad.net/matlab-bgl/+question/93601](https://answers.launchpad.net/matlab-bgl/+question/93601)

Comment: @shamalaia how does that help him in R?

Comment: question is tagged matlab.. maybe it works for him

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The RBGL package within bioconductor has what you are looking for. RBGL provides an interface to the Boost library for graph analysis (C++)

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("RBGL")

library(RBGL)
library(igraph)

set.seed(1234)
g <- erdos.renyi.game(20, 1/5) ##Make an igraph graph
plot(g)

g <- as_graphnel(g) ## Convert igraph object to graphNEL object for planarity testing
boyerMyrvoldPlanarityTest(g)

# [1] FALSE

g <- erdos.renyi.game(20, 1/8)
plot(g)

g <- as_graphnel(g)
boyerMyrvoldPlanarityTest(g)
# [1] TRUE
```

### Non Planar graph

[image: Non-planar]

### Planar graph

[image: PLanar]

Comment: Apologies for not being clearer - I need help on how to do it in R not in MATLAB.

Comment: This is an R solution

Comment: It's been removed from CRAN and doesn't work under latest R version. Any ideas?

Comment: It is in the Bioconductor repository. I have edited my answer to show how to install the package.

Comment: I'm assuming to test plnarity, the graph has to be in a `graphNEL` format?

Comment: Also, be worth mentioning that this only works for undirected graphs!